# Specify iOS app installation directory

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, installation, info-plist

Is there a way to specify the installation directory for an iOS app?
Apps should be installed in /var/mobile/Applications/app_directory so how and where can I specify this app_directory?

I believe it should be in the info-plist but I can't find anything in the documentation.

To be clear, I would of course like to define this at compile/package-time, I do not want the user to select the directory at install-time which is obviously not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Hollance, you can not change the directory. This is happening because each app will run in his own sandbox folder and have no access to other applications folders.

From apple:
"Sandboxing—All iOS apps are placed in sandboxes to protect the system and other apps. The structure of the sandbox affects the placement of your app’s files and has implications for data backups and some app-related features."

App folder names are actual UID names (not the actual app name).

You can read about this in the iPhone App Programming Guide under "The Application Sandbox".

Comment: I have heard Android characterized as an incomplete mess (that is, the OS is incomplete, and it is a mess to program in).  Apps are not sandboxed and can do whatever to each other, it is amazing to me there aren't more viruses and worms.  This is exactly what iOS is avoiding - the nastier parts of the Wild West.  I believe it is your unique App ID that Apple generates for you for iTunes Connect, but whatever - what do you really care what the folder is named?  You can obtain it from the bundle and used it as a variable within your app.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you cannot. The OS will name and create that directory for you.

Comment: Sure, but it does so based on something. I believe it is the "top level" of the bundle identifier domain. So if that is "com.company.game" it will put it in "/game". The problem is when another company has created an app with the "game" identifier... I could be wrong, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: is not put directly on the ../game but in a folder generated with a uniqu UID

Comment: There is zero risk of another app interfereing with your app install. When you establish an app ID in the provisioning portal Apple gives it a Unique ID.   You can imagine the problems with half a billion apps out there if they didn't.

Comment: The reason I posted my question is that my in-development app was put in the directory of another app that had the same top-level domain, for example /Game. I assume that this is because it's installed from Xcode/TesFlight and that once it goes through the AppStore the unique ID will be used instead...